# How can I change the size of an item when held in Minecraft 1.8.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm trying to change the size of an iron sword so that it's bigger when held.  I’m in Minecraft Java version 1.8.9.

I have a file named `iron_sword.json` and it’s directory is `assets/textures/models/item/iron_sword.json`
It’s content is the following.

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/iron_sword"
    },
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 90, -35 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.25, -4.2 ],
            "scale": [ 1.2, 1.2, 1.2 ]
        },
        "firstperson": {
            "rotation": [ 0, -135, 25 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 4, 2 ],
            "scale": [ 1.7, 1.7, 1.7 ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t know what is wrong.  Is it the file directory or the content of the file?

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to increase the scale for both third and first person views. Your current scale is:

(third person)

```
[ 1.2, 1.2, 1.2 ]
```

(first person)

```
[ 1.7, 1.7, 1.7 ]
```

Try increasing the scale up a bit, matching for each value in the string. For example, below I've increased the ratios by 0.3 each. This can be a test to see if it works for you.

(third person)

```
[ 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 ]
```

(first person)

```
[ 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 ]
```